# DataObjects.NET: a good (flawless, documented, support) ORM?

Tags: c#, orm, dataobjects.net

I am looking for ORM frameworks, came along to NHibernate, Genome, L2S, Entity Framework and now the DataObjects.NET.. So far a I read the documentation it seems pretty cabable, but have you ever tried this ORM?

Any issues/bugs with DO.NET would be approciated :)

Comment: I don't know if I'd use **flawless** to describe anything in software development.

Answer (score 3):

I used DataObjects.Net v4.
It supports VS 2010 and .Net 4.0 and it is really good ORM.
It's easy to use and it constructs the database automatically so you do not design the database and reverse engineer it to classes like some other ORMs.
The only thing that was so annoying about it is the Session management and switching mechanism in case of web applications. I think even this is being taken care of in version 4.4 currently under development.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) as well. I think this is probably the best .NET ORM out there.

Comment: ditto. Iffn ya gonna pay money, buy the best. Rock solid and ultimately extensible.

Comment: Genom-e isn't actively developed anymore as a product, only for their own customers.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that this question sound a lot like an informercial, there's a big problem with DataObjects.Net - it's dual-licensed as a GPL or commercial w/o evaluation. So the answer is - **no, I have not tried it and it is quite unlikely I will try it**.

I have no beef with GPL (though I do not like it for various reasons), or dual-licensed products - after all the license choice is a right to the copyright holder. However, I also want to reserve that right for my software as well. I am writing commercial software, which I have no problem releasing as open source, but under a license of my choice. If I am to adopt a new ORM, I want, nay - I *need* to be able to release a CTP preview of my product to a limited set of customers for real-life testing. And that would mean I either have to splurge the money for DO.Net upfront without knowing whether my investment will benefit me; or I have to release my sources under a license that effectively takes away the control over my app from me and has the potential to ruin my business by commoditizing my product.

Now, if there was a limited evaluation license, say one month noncommercial use, I might consider giving it a quick trial and see how it works.

If a product wants commercial adoption, it needs to have a risk-free way for early adopters to evaluate it.

Comment: He said "nay" :)

Answer (score 0):

Does DataObjects.NET support SQL identity columns yet? I abandoned v3 because I couldn't find a way to support identity columns.

Comment: No, it still doesn't, but you can use your own key generators there (i.e. the main requirement is: keys must be generated before insertion). v4.0 is quite different from this point from v3 - in particular you aren't limited to few integer key types.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879333/can-dataobjects-net-support-sql-identity-columns